# symfony caching of mobile view / one url with 2 sf_formats

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4

I activated caching for my app. Works great. I have have a mobile format using

```
layout.m.php
```

Which is set to

```
sf_format: m
```

So when i open an URL with the specific userAgent i don't get the layout.m but instead the cached version of the original and vice versa.

**how to config. the cache specific to sf_format?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to [cache partials and components](http://www.symfony-project.org/gentle-introduction/1_4/en/12-Caching#chapter_12_sub_caching_a_partial_or_component) instead of the whole application. At least for the action/template where you're detecting the device type of the user.

It seems that you applied cache to a dynamic part where you're looking for every request if the user is using a mobile device...

Comment: Thanks dlondero, that's exactly the point, i need to know how to set the cache for a partial/component **depending** on the sf_format. I can't se an option to f.e. disable caching of a partial when used by mobile but keep it activated when used by non-mobile sf-format.

Comment: But I don't think you need to change your partials or components cache, you just need to check the sf_format before you render your templates. So only not caching that code you can handle more behaviors for your application.